# What's the history on the option separator of GNU sed?

Tags: linux, sed

They say GNU sed supports using any character following the command character as a separator for command options, like the following.

```
echo abc | sed 'y%abc%ABC%'
```

But I can't find the documentation of this in [the official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). What is the history on this? Is the documentation missing? Or is this an undocumented feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there, under [Other Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands):

> (The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given y command.)

The same applies to `s///` and [The `s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own stupid question.

It's not true that sed supports any character following the command character as a separator for command options. Only the 's' and 'y' commands support this feature. The documentation says these in the section 3.3 and 3.5.

> The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command.

> (The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given y command.)

Answer (score 2):

On "**What is the history on this?**":

I found "*SED — A Non-interactive Text Editor*" by Lee E. McMahon, dated "August 15, 1978".
In section "3.2. Substitute Function" it says (about "s<pattern><replacement><flags>") on page 5:

> The  argument contains a pattern, exactly like the patterns in addresses (see 2.2 above). The only difference between <pattern> and a context address is that the context address must be delimited by slash (‘/’) characters; <pattern> may be delimited by any character other than space or newline.

So the history is that it goes back to the very roots of `sed`.